# React.js component rendering the same images from Instagram repeatedly if current route is refreshed

Tags: reactjs, http, visual-glitch, instafeedjs

I need help with figuring out how not to make my react.js component rerender same images from Instagram and add them to the exisitng in the view.

I have a [react-instafeed](https://github.com/JeromeFitz/react-instafeed) container in my react.js component, which is fetching 20 latest images from my Instagram account and renders them in a neat grid. The [react-instafeed](https://github.com/JeromeFitz/react-instafeed) element is a wrapper around the popular [instafeed.js](http://instafeedjs.com/) framework and makes the same methods and configurations available in react.js environment.

On initial load it fetches the images and renders them. However, if the current route is refreshed (by pressing the button in the header navigation, for example), it fetches all 20 images once again and adds them in the view, and so on.

I tried dealing with it by setting something like 'loaded' in the state in the 'success, or 'after' methods of the instafeed, but that's clearly not working and is anti-pattern.

I tried doing it with componentDidMount, with the result of a doubled http call on initial rendering and 20x2 images at once.

Apparently, setting state is not the right strategy in this case. How could I either prevent the element from making a n-th call to Instagram, or maybe destroying the element on componentWillUpdate()?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate is probably what you want, but you may need to move your instafeed into it's own stateful component if you need other components around it to rerender

Comment: Doesn't look like that library offers control and refetches on every render. Would be simpler to just use Instagram's api directly `/users/self/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN&count=20` and map over the results. You could call the api in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak that's brilliant, exactly what I need at the moment. I would like to mark your answer as accepted but I don't see a checkbox for that.

Comment: @RickJolly thanks for the answer, I have been considering that too. I am going to stick with returning false in the shouldComponentUpdate() for now, but later I will probably refactor to just fetch the posts without the instafeed.